# Find Document for 1 Collection

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am trying to get the data from the collection "Symbole", with this code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            MainAsync(args).Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        string uri = "mongodb://Host:Port/DBName";
        var client = new MongoClient(uri);
        var db = client.GetDatabase("DBName");
        var col = db.GetCollection<BOSBourse>("TableName");

        var list = await col.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();

        foreach (var doc in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(doc);
        }

    }

    class BOSBourse
    {
        public ObjectId ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But it throws an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: One or more errors occurred.

After I add try/catch I see a big exception:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.FormatException: Element '_id' does not match any field or property of class MongoDBCRUD.Program+BOSBourse.
>      at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context)
>
> [...]
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at MongoDBCRUD.Program.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\amin-\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MongoDBCRUD\MongoDBCRUD\Program.cs:line 60<---

Event if I modify the :

```
public ObjectId ID { get; set; }
```

To

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Still the same error occurs.

**Update (Solution)
In the class BOSBourse, just modify the price type from string to double**

Comment: Known issue of the < 2 driver, use `public ObjectId _id { get; set; }` (or `Id`, `id`, anyway not `ID`), try searching. You also don't need to include that _entire_ stack trace.

Comment: that's my bad, I have 2 data contain 2 id, delete an the same error